# Echarts4r : Create stacked area chart with percentage from total in tooltip

Tags: r, visualization, echarts

I need to make stacked area chart using the `echarts4r`. In spite of great examples on [javascript](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-examples/public/editor.html?c=area-stack) I can't find the solution how to make the area chart stacked using R.

Ideally it is also necessary to add to the chart the tooltip with percentage from total as in my example using `highcharter` package.

```
library(echarts4r)
library(highcharter)

set.seed(2018)
dt <- data.frame(a =1:10,
                 x = rnorm(10, mean = 20, sd = 5), 
                 y = rnorm(10, mean = 20, sd = 5),
                 z = rnorm(10, mean = 10, sd = 5))


echarts <- dt %>%
  e_charts(a) %>%
  e_area(x, stack = "stack", origin = 'start') %>%
  e_area(y, stack = "stack", origin = 'start') %>%
  e_area(z, stack = "stack", origin = 'start') %>%
  e_grid(left = '4%', right = '3%', bottom = '10%', containLabel = true) %>%
  e_tooltip(trigger = "axis", axisPointer = list(type = 'cross')) %>%
  e_toolbox(left = 'right', itemSize = 15, top = 22) %>%
  e_toolbox_feature("saveAsImage", title = 'save as image') %>%
  e_toolbox_feature("dataZoom", title = list(zoom = "zoom", back = "back")) %>%
  e_toolbox_feature("restore", title = 'restore') %>%
  e_theme("infographic") %>%
  e_legend(type = 'scroll', bottom = 1)

echarts

highchart <-  highchart() %>%
  hc_xAxis(categories = dt$a) %>%
  hc_add_series(data = dt$x, name = 'x') %>%
  hc_add_series(data = dt$y, name = 'y') %>%
  hc_add_series(data = dt$z, name = 'z') %>%
  hc_chart(type = "area") %>%
  hc_plotOptions(area = list(stacking = "normal", lineColor = "#ffffff",
                             lineWidth = 1, marker = list( lineWidth = 1,
                                                           lineColor = "#ffffff"))) %>%
  hc_legend(reversed = FALSE) %>%
  hc_tooltip(crosshairs = TRUE, backgroundColor = "#FCFFC5", shared = TRUE, borderWidth = 5, 
             pointFormat = "<span style=\"color:{series.color}\">{series.name}</span>:
                 <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b> ({point.y:,.0f} users)<br/>") 

highchart
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of doing it, very similar to `highcharter`:

```
dt %>%
    e_charts(a) %>%
    e_area(x, stack = "stack", origin = 'start') %>%
    e_area(y, stack = "stack", origin = 'start') %>%
    e_area(z, stack = "stack", origin = 'start') %>%
    e_grid(left = '4%', right = '3%', bottom = '10%', containLabel = TRUE) %>%
    e_toolbox(left = 'right', itemSize = 15, top = 22) %>%
    e_toolbox_feature("saveAsImage", title = 'save as image') %>%
    e_toolbox_feature("dataZoom", title = list(zoom = "zoom", back = "back")) %>%
    e_toolbox_feature("restore", title = 'restore') %>%
    e_theme("infographic") %>%
    e_legend(type = 'scroll', bottom = 1) %>%
    e_tooltip( trigger ="axis",
              formatter = htmlwidgets::JS("
              function(params){
                var tot = params[0].name + params[1].value[0] + params[2].value[0]
                function perc(x){return(Math.round((x/tot) * 100))};
                return('x: ' + params[0].value[1] + ' (' + perc(params[0].value[1]) + '%)' + '<br>' + 'y:' + params[1].value[1] + ' (' + perc(params[1].value[1]) + '%)' + '<br>' + 'z:' + params[2].value[1] + ' (' + perc(params[2].value[1]) + '%)')
                                          }
              ")
              )
```

More information on tooltips [on the website](https://echarts4r.john-coene.com/articles/tooltip.html).

**EDIT** Thanks for your comment, sorry I omitted part of the question. For some reason, a reason I was not aware of, stacking only works with categorical x axis. Below are two options to get there:

```
# options one use character or vector.
dt %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(a = as.character(a)) %>% 
    e_charts(a) %>%
    e_area(x, stack = "stack") %>%
    e_area(y, stack = "stack") %>%
    e_area(z, stack = "stack") %>%
    e_grid(left = '4%', right = '3%', bottom = '10%') %>%
    e_toolbox(left = 'right', itemSize = 15, top = 22) %>%
    e_toolbox_feature("saveAsImage", title = 'save as image') %>%
    e_toolbox_feature("restore", title = 'restore') %>%
    e_theme("infographic") %>%
    e_legend(bottom = 1) %>%
    e_tooltip( trigger ="axis",
               formatter = htmlwidgets::JS("
                                           function(params){
                                           var tot = params[0].name + params[1].value[0] + params[2].value[0]
                                           function perc(x){return(Math.round((x/tot) * 100))};
                                           return('x: ' + params[0].value[1] + ' (' + perc(params[0].value[1]) + '%)' + '<br>' + 'y:' + params[1].value[1] + ' (' + perc(params[1].value[1]) + '%)' + '<br>' + 'z:' + params[2].value[1] + ' (' + perc(params[2].value[1]) + '%)')
                                           }
                                           ")
               ) 

# option 2
# Use e_x_axis to change the axis type
dt %>% 
    e_charts(a) %>%
    e_area(x, stack = "stack") %>%
    e_area(y, stack = "stack") %>%
    e_area(z, stack = "stack") %>%
    e_grid(left = '4%', right = '3%', bottom = '10%') %>%
    e_toolbox(left = 'right', itemSize = 15, top = 22) %>%
    e_toolbox_feature("saveAsImage", title = 'save as image') %>%
    e_toolbox_feature("restore", title = 'restore') %>%
    e_theme("infographic") %>%
    e_legend(bottom = 1) %>%
    e_tooltip( trigger ="axis",
               formatter = htmlwidgets::JS("
                                           function(params){
                                           var tot = params[0].name + params[1].value[0] + params[2].value[0]
                                           function perc(x){return(Math.round((x/tot) * 100))};
                                           return('x: ' + params[0].value[1] + ' (' + perc(params[0].value[1]) + '%)' + '<br>' + 'y:' + params[1].value[1] + ' (' + perc(params[1].value[1]) + '%)' + '<br>' + 'z:' + params[2].value[1] + ' (' + perc(params[2].value[1]) + '%)')
                                           }
                                           ")
               ) %>%
  e_x_axis(type = "category")
```

Comment: Thanks for your help with tooltip. My main problem was not in tooltip but in layers. I wanted that each layer was over another. But in my case each layer start from zero. I used your code and received result like that https://prnt.sc/l0w5pd